# adding body data for a post angular 4

Tags: angular

I am adding content from an input element into a body request. so I can pull back data based on the member Id and Partner Id, I have tried many things with no luck and help would be appreciated. I would like to use 2 way databinding and the template driven forms
I have the FormsModule in place.
here is the code

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

const guid = function () {
  return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
    s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
};

function s4() {
  return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
    .toString(16)
    .substring(1);
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data',
  templateUrl: './data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data.component.css']
})
export class DataComponent implements OnInit {
  memberId = 'SVR17066GYA';
  partnerId = 101;

  constructor(public http: Http) { }

  getMembers() {

    // const bodyGetInfo = {
    //   'PartnerId': this.partnerId,
    //   'MemberId': this.memberId,
    //   'Product': 'Default',
    //   'CorrelationId': guid()
    // };

    const bodyGetInfo = {
      'PartnerId' : this.partnerId,
      'MemberId' : this.memberId,
      'Product' : 'Default',
      'CorrelationId' : guid()
    };

    return this.http.post('url' )
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.getMembers()
      .subscribe(members => {
        console.log(members);
      })
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="memberId" >
{{memberId}}
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="partnerId">
{{partnerId}}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to set response from the server to your inputs in html?

So first of all, you are sending the request in ngInit, and i guess you want to send a request after you fullfill your Form and click submit button, so you need to send a post on (click) event from the submit button, that you need to add to your html. Correct me if i get it wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I was hoping to achieve was to send the request upon adding the data to the form without a submit button, however, I can see that this would also cause another set of problems in that the input would send upon each character being typed into the form. I will add a submit button as suggested :)

Answer (score 0):

ok, I figured it out and I thought I would post the new code that works for template driven forms. I will build in reactive forms next and post as well once I get it. Hope this helps someone else :)

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

const guid = function () {
  return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
    s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
};

function s4() {
  return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
    .toString(16)
    .substring(1);
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data',
  templateUrl: './data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data.component.css']
})
export class DataComponent {

  memberId: string;
  partnerId: number;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
  }

  submit(f) {
    console.log(f.value.memberId);
    console.log(f.value.partnerId);
    this.memberId = f.value.memberId;
    this.partnerId = f.value.partnerId;

    const bodyGetInfo = {
      'PartnerId': this.partnerId,
      'MemberId': this.memberId,
      'Product': 'Default',
      'CorrelationId': guid()
    };

    return this.http.post('url')
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res.json())
      });
  }
}
```

```html
<form novalidate #formData="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(formData)">
  <input
    type="text"
    ngModel
    name="memberId">
    
  <input
    type="text"
    ngModel
    name="partnerId">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```